# Wireless power transmission calculations

Tags: power, wireless, power-engineering

[image]

I have been able to calculate and fix components for the transmitter circuit of wireless power transmission system but I am still having some challenges. They are:
1. How can I calculate theoretically the gain of the mosfets?
2. How can I calculate the voltage induced at the receiver circuit?
3. How can I calculate the values of the components I can use to rectify the received voltage? I am working with 14MHz frequency.

Note: I tried to use the formular, coupling coefficient (K)* magnetic field (B) to calculate the induced voltage but I got a rediculously little number.
So, I really need answers to help me move forward. I would also appreciate a better circuit diagram that can transfer up to 24 volts.

Comment: What formula was it that you tried? What distance did you assume between tx and rx coils? What rx tuning capacitance did you use?

Comment: Also note that you are not transferring voltage, you are transferring inductive power.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some app notes related specifically to this topic that may help:

http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/AN138fc.pdf

http://www.digikey.com/~/media/Images/Product%20Highlights/W/Wurth%20Electronics%20Inc/wireless-power-solutions/wurth-wireless-power-charging.pdf?la=en-US

and here is one with all boring the theory:
http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/175567/175567.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nedd. I will go through these resources and get back to you.

Comment: But, when you say that what is being transmitted is inductive power, I really want to know more about that. Is there something like a formular to calculate that apart from the traditional formulae?

Comment: Hello Nedd. I tried to simulate a simple wireless power transmission system on Proteus but it is not working. Please, do you have any idea on what the problem might be?